# APOPT solver finds different solution every time

Tags: optimization, gekko

I'm using gekko to solve a MINLP problem. I'm using the APOPT solver since is the only one that can provide integer solution, which are strictly needed in my case.

The issue I have is that every time I run the solver I have a different solution, even for very small cases, so I can't be sure about the optimality of the solutions. From some solutions to others there are important differences in the objective final value.

I've noticed that only 1 iteration takes place, and I don't know if it should be like this. Also, it runs for less than 1 second when it could run longer and find better solutions.

Below the output of one of this runs:

```
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :           86
   Constants    :            0
   Variables    :          606
   Intermediates:            0
   Connections  :          806
   Equations    :         1046
   Residuals    :         1046
 
 Number of state variables:            606
 Number of total equations: -          172
 Number of slack variables: -           40
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :            394
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      0.38 NLPi:   28 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    0 Obj:  1.27E+09 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   0.38800000000628643      sec
 Objective      :    1271480486.0000000     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

I would appreciate any advice on how to tweak the solver so I can have consistent solutions. Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I'm adding the code (reduced version). Basically what I'm trying to do is finding the best location for n warehouse based on the demand of m cities, which are represented by the corresponding hexagon in the h3 library.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
from random import randint
import pandas as pd



if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    n_warehouses = 6
    df_aggreg = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'hex_id_basic': {32: 0, 12: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 22: 4, 24: 5, 38: 6, 8: 7, 19: 8, 27: 9, 21: 10, 25: 11, 28: 12, 26: 13, 29: 14, 30: 15, 31: 16, 1: 17, 20: 18, 18: 19, 17: 20, 33: 21, 35: 22, 14: 23, 13: 24, 11: 25, 10: 26, 36: 27, 6: 28, 5: 29, 4: 30, 16: 31, 34: 32, 0: 33, 23: 34, 15: 35, 9: 36, 37: 37, 7: 38, 39: 39}, 'value': {32: 1808, 12: 847, 2: 847, 3: 847, 22: 847, 24: 847, 38: 847, 8: 847, 19: 847, 27: 847, 21: 452, 25: 452, 28: 452, 26: 452, 29: 452, 30: 452, 31: 452, 1: 452, 20: 452, 18: 452, 17: 452, 33: 452, 35: 452, 14: 452, 13: 452, 11: 452, 10: 452, 36: 452, 6: 452, 5: 452, 4: 452, 16: 452, 34: 169, 0: 169, 23: 84, 15: 84, 9: 84, 37: 84, 7: 84, 39: 84}})
    distance_matrix = [[0, 278320, 302712, 117682, 283287, 225645, 303065, 258900, 252165, 453768, 389125, 305694, 377415, 445329, 176671, 16098, 95378, 272352, 153948, 247011, 153063, 175620, 184734, 253592, 235204, 275271, 204377, 140151, 270207, 254950, 364642, 92383, 239928, 300635, 394936, 291140, 293377, 205417, 253778, 313127], [278320, 0, 144398, 187013, 244571, 107924, 257813, 279533, 334530, 195669, 205157, 84028, 109937, 187707, 427560, 265135, 188779, 292672, 307462, 280094, 408319, 281660, 131476, 440829, 46693, 204251, 233509, 147273, 263519, 267077, 185835, 310005, 254863, 323378, 119817, 407585, 280337, 171576, 280105, 261055], [302712, 144398, 0, 185183, 377007, 234161, 392715, 170354, 237346, 307577, 347861, 228110, 138929, 301200, 476655, 286696, 244493, 179154, 254571, 176769, 387398, 378208, 238178, 372115, 163476, 79788, 152001, 222356, 146928, 158337, 62584, 289416, 375428, 203381, 217686, 310387, 155900, 289533, 173468, 397435], [117682, 187013, 185183, 0, 291864, 179791, 311714, 170740, 192926, 379238, 347869, 240050, 272172, 370968, 293195, 101616, 87586, 185977, 129253, 162328, 222594, 233040, 150108, 262697, 153805, 162481, 109099, 101869, 173375, 162759, 246974, 123207, 265470, 218641, 306739, 255114, 197339, 195959, 167223, 320151], [283287, 244571, 377007, 291864, 0, 142846, 20212, 455483, 484791, 287216, 161617, 183085, 340463, 280631, 326676, 282534, 212575, 470828, 409823, 449527, 434084, 135211, 148574, 531347, 213849, 411617, 394742, 190552, 450777, 445332, 427673, 367985, 53066, 504293, 288485, 544788, 473256, 96874, 453151, 29897], [225645, 107924, 234161, 179791, 142846, 0, 158910, 325969, 365598, 232092, 169623, 84652, 214438, 223750, 344437, 216987, 130954, 340949, 308549, 322092, 374352, 178834, 41429, 440518, 71333, 272261, 268233, 88085, 317511, 314784, 285789, 286639, 147154, 374185, 190689, 432588, 338741, 64095, 324564, 164244], [303065, 257813, 392715, 311714, 20212, 158910, 0, 474649, 504627, 286841, 156847, 192075, 350549, 280649, 341260, 302511, 232768, 489976, 430017, 468858, 453490, 151205, 167295, 551499, 229266, 429328, 414077, 210234, 469552, 464393, 442147, 388101, 68990, 523448, 294341, 564878, 491892, 116277, 472394, 10359], [258900, 279533, 170354, 170740, 455483, 325969, 474649, 0, 68930, 467349, 478557, 358082, 308273, 460170, 428178, 244879, 258325, 15394, 131661, 13671, 271974, 403214, 307634, 213649, 272011, 90917, 61801, 266220, 26455, 12593, 202481, 195575, 434164, 48812, 379747, 140257, 39308, 358628, 6107, 482200], [252165, 334530, 237346, 192926, 484791, 365598, 504627, 68930, 0, 526826, 526392, 408559, 373685, 519349, 407413, 240840, 276462, 66186, 101574, 60620, 226811, 414422, 341075, 147167, 320118, 158889, 101274, 294543, 95127, 79800, 271409, 171262, 456912, 68984, 441013, 74111, 100302, 388712, 64684, 513007], [453768, 195669, 307577, 379238, 287216, 232092, 286841, 467349, 526826, 0, 136244, 148461, 178102, 8441, 573471, 443171, 358499, 479086, 502816, 469837, 595669, 392502, 273266, 636429, 225844, 383011, 426871, 313638, 447989, 454756, 317090, 500323, 328239, 507228, 90088, 600610, 461075, 278672, 468809, 282694], [389125, 205157, 347861, 347869, 161617, 169623, 156847, 478557, 526392, 136244, 0, 121715, 255074, 131581, 475633, 382466, 297470, 492617, 477097, 477118, 540843, 284992, 206940, 609805, 206849, 408806, 425937, 256909, 465228, 466469, 379467, 455895, 209773, 524589, 174173, 596319, 483539, 187375, 478271, 151054], [305694, 84028, 228110, 240050, 183085, 84652, 192075, 358082, 408559, 148461, 121715, 0, 158796, 140049, 428839, 295540, 210329, 371886, 368057, 357279, 450043, 256851, 125251, 502181, 89028, 287097, 307444, 165570, 343975, 345858, 265337, 357240, 207855, 403529, 110982, 479964, 361969, 139306, 358064, 193009], [377415, 109937, 138929, 272172, 340463, 214438, 350549, 308273, 373685, 178102, 255074, 158796, 0, 173125, 534732, 362967, 293628, 317765, 374520, 313604, 493385, 391108, 241276, 501197, 156178, 218494, 280742, 254733, 285601, 295994, 139047, 393079, 358593, 342270, 90310, 447455, 294687, 278510, 310960, 351759], [445329, 187707, 301200, 370968, 280631, 223750, 280649, 460170, 519349, 8441, 131581, 140049, 173125, 0, 565355, 434730, 350062, 472002, 494725, 462533, 587263, 384786, 264901, 628392, 217517, 376220, 419266, 305200, 440993, 447576, 311937, 491975, 321105, 500318, 84177, 593082, 454296, 270683, 461573, 276700], [176671, 427560, 476655, 293195, 326676, 344437, 341260, 428178, 407413, 573471, 475633, 428839, 534732, 565355, 0, 192659, 241685, 440309, 306114, 415366, 213722, 192267, 305547, 353506, 381057, 451860, 378110, 280381, 442537, 425977, 539074, 236503, 273614, 465255, 533298, 426186, 464854, 295413, 422602, 351173], [16098, 265135, 286696, 101616, 282534, 216987, 302511, 244879, 240840, 443171, 382466, 295540, 362967, 434730, 192659, 0, 86037, 258560, 144482, 233219, 158401, 180937, 176621, 250690, 222751, 259395, 189468, 130132, 255508, 240568, 348587, 87437, 241145, 287389, 382525, 282778, 278823, 201018, 239867, 312431], [95378, 188779, 244493, 87586, 212575, 130954, 232768, 258325, 276462, 358499, 297470, 210329, 293628, 350062, 241685, 86037, 0, 273554, 197249, 249773, 243741, 146171, 90840, 321549, 143532, 241689, 196668, 44890, 260330, 250266, 306721, 160762, 180583, 306135, 302150, 332965, 284225, 121772, 254773, 241969], [272352, 292672, 179154, 185977, 470828, 340949, 489976, 15394, 66186, 479086, 492617, 371886, 317765, 472002, 440309, 258560, 273554, 0, 140627, 25344, 279225, 418280, 322922, 213131, 286282, 99366, 77144, 281612, 32238, 26277, 207287, 206362, 449552, 33473, 391005, 133626, 34477, 373979, 19000, 497504], [153948, 307462, 254571, 129253, 409823, 308549, 430017, 131661, 101574, 502816, 477097, 368057, 374520, 494725, 306114, 144482, 197249, 140627, 0, 117996, 141824, 323726, 276426, 134201, 280163, 191685, 105340, 226127, 152834, 133897, 305377, 69716, 375475, 161033, 424673, 138867, 170911, 317471, 125583, 439203], [247011, 280094, 176769, 162328, 449527, 322092, 468858, 13671, 60620, 469837, 477118, 357279, 313604, 462533, 415366, 233219, 249773, 25344, 117996, 0, 258348, 393955, 302253, 202640, 270296, 98356, 54784, 259602, 38118, 20016, 211973, 182205, 426898, 56395, 382945, 133870, 52974, 352657, 7588, 476592], [153063, 408319, 387398, 222594, 434084, 374352, 453490, 271974, 226811, 595669, 540843, 450043, 493385, 587263, 213722, 158401, 243741, 279225, 141824, 258348, 0, 314904, 334581, 140210, 370743, 331489, 244983, 286515, 294300, 275249, 442428, 100328, 387881, 294243, 528076, 223497, 311245, 358451, 265867, 463708], [175620, 281660, 378208, 233040, 135211, 178834, 151205, 403214, 414422, 392502, 284992, 256851, 391108, 384786, 192267, 180937, 146171, 418280, 323726, 393955, 314904, 0, 150414, 428871, 237099, 386147, 341933, 156045, 406310, 395685, 438153, 267684, 82364, 450314, 367218, 462586, 430241, 117601, 399353, 161423], [184734, 131476, 238178, 150108, 148574, 41429, 167295, 307634, 341075, 273266, 206940, 125251, 241276, 264901, 305547, 176621, 90840, 322922, 276426, 302253, 334581, 150414, 0, 406344, 86738, 264273, 247556, 50786, 302265, 297224, 294689, 249321, 137664, 356394, 227861, 405170, 324686, 53055, 305544, 174613], [253592, 440829, 372115, 262697, 531347, 440518, 551499, 213649, 147167, 636429, 609805, 502181, 501197, 628392, 353506, 250690, 321549, 213131, 134201, 202640, 140210, 428871, 406344, 0, 414364, 298374, 221122, 355576, 240067, 222654, 413797, 163640, 491733, 212409, 556786, 103608, 247427, 443322, 208464, 561173], [235204, 46693, 163476, 153805, 213849, 71333, 229266, 272011, 320118, 225844, 206849, 89028, 156178, 217517, 381057, 222751, 143532, 286282, 280163, 270296, 370743, 237099, 86738, 414364, 0, 208101, 219280, 101025, 259858, 260053, 214484, 274518, 217001, 318654, 159780, 391112, 279361, 131548, 271564, 233971], [275271, 204251, 79788, 162481, 411617, 272261, 429328, 90917, 158889, 383011, 408806, 287097, 218494, 376220, 451860, 259395, 241689, 99366, 191685, 98356, 331489, 386147, 264273, 298374, 208101, 0, 86592, 233845, 67147, 79218, 115829, 239530, 400051, 124610, 293938, 231168, 78076, 317319, 94401, 435547], [204377, 233509, 152001, 109099, 394742, 268233, 414077, 61801, 101274, 426871, 425937, 307444, 280742, 419266, 378110, 189468, 196668, 77144, 105340, 54784, 244983, 341933, 247556, 221122, 219280, 86592, 0, 204896, 66374, 53769, 200202, 155140, 372506, 110258, 342408, 174094, 90128, 297872, 58728, 421827], [140151, 147273, 222356, 101869, 190552, 88085, 210234, 266220, 294543, 313638, 256909, 165570, 254733, 305200, 280381, 130132, 44890, 281612, 226127, 259602, 286515, 156045, 50786, 355576, 101025, 233845, 204896, 0, 263729, 256622, 282929, 198993, 168664, 314976, 258111, 356656, 286974, 94168, 263557, 218490], [270207, 263519, 146928, 173375, 450777, 317511, 469552, 26455, 95127, 447989, 465228, 343975, 285601, 440993, 442537, 255508, 260330, 32238, 152834, 38118, 294300, 406310, 302265, 240067, 259858, 67147, 66374, 263729, 0, 19120, 176392, 213505, 432376, 59886, 359568, 165204, 23979, 354255, 31668, 476705], [254950, 267077, 158337, 162759, 445332, 314784, 464393, 12593, 79800, 454756, 466469, 345858, 295994, 447576, 425977, 240568, 250266, 26277, 133897, 20016, 275249, 395685, 297224, 222654, 260053, 79218, 53769, 256622, 19120, 0, 192090, 195450, 424902, 59414, 367175, 152072, 38895, 348532, 15183, 471835], [364642, 185835, 62584, 246974, 427673, 285789, 442147, 202481, 271409, 317090, 379467, 265337, 139047, 311937, 539074, 348587, 306721, 207287, 305377, 211973, 442428, 438153, 294689, 413797, 214484, 115829, 200202, 282929, 176392, 192090, 0, 346396, 430496, 224040, 228276, 340846, 177161, 344487, 206946, 445989], [92383, 310005, 289416, 123207, 367985, 286639, 388101, 195575, 171262, 500323, 455895, 357240, 393079, 491975, 236503, 87437, 160762, 206362, 69716, 182205, 100328, 267684, 249321, 163640, 274518, 239530, 155140, 198993, 213505, 195450, 346396, 0, 328145, 229377, 429805, 200778, 233973, 281930, 189695, 397850], [239928, 254863, 375428, 265470, 53066, 147154, 68990, 434164, 456912, 328239, 209773, 207855, 358593, 321105, 273614, 241145, 180583, 449552, 375475, 426898, 387881, 82364, 137664, 491733, 217001, 400051, 372506, 168664, 432376, 424902, 430496, 328145, 0, 482764, 317893, 512855, 455638, 86038, 431229, 79283], [300635, 323378, 203381, 218641, 504293, 374185, 523448, 48812, 68984, 507228, 524589, 403529, 342270, 500318, 465255, 287389, 306135, 33473, 161033, 56395, 294243, 450314, 356394, 212409, 318654, 124610, 110258, 314976, 59886, 59414, 224040, 229377, 482764, 0, 418433, 121305, 47807, 407440, 51547, 530978], [394936, 119817, 217686, 306739, 288485, 190689, 294341, 379747, 441013, 90088, 174173, 110982, 90310, 84177, 533298, 382525, 302150, 391005, 424673, 382945, 528076, 367218, 227861, 556786, 159780, 293938, 342408, 258111, 359568, 367175, 228276, 429805, 317893, 418433, 0, 515064, 371904, 249637, 381509, 293301], [291140, 407585, 310387, 255114, 544788, 432588, 564878, 140257, 74111, 600610, 596319, 479964, 447455, 593082, 426186, 282778, 332965, 133626, 138867, 133870, 223497, 462586, 405170, 103608, 391112, 231168, 174094, 356656, 165204, 152072, 340846, 200778, 512855, 121305, 515064, 0, 164624, 450245, 136922, 573716], [293377, 280337, 155900, 197339, 473256, 338741, 491892, 39308, 100302, 461075, 483539, 361969, 294687, 454296, 464854, 278823, 284225, 34477, 170911, 52974, 311245, 430241, 324686, 247427, 279361, 78076, 90128, 286974, 23979, 38895, 177161, 233973, 455638, 47807, 371904, 164624, 0, 376916, 45412, 498907], [205417, 171576, 289533, 195959, 96874, 64095, 116277, 358628, 388712, 278672, 187375, 139306, 278510, 270683, 295413, 201018, 121772, 373979, 317471, 352657, 358451, 117601, 53055, 443322, 131548, 317319, 297872, 94168, 354255, 348532, 344487, 281930, 86038, 407440, 249637, 450245, 376916, 0, 356278, 124356], [253778, 280105, 173468, 167223, 453151, 324564, 472394, 6107, 64684, 468809, 478271, 358064, 310960, 461573, 422602, 239867, 254773, 19000, 125583, 7588, 265867, 399353, 305544, 208464, 271564, 94401, 58728, 263557, 31668, 15183, 206946, 189695, 431229, 51547, 381509, 136922, 45412, 356278, 0, 480029], [313127, 261055, 397435, 320151, 29897, 164244, 10359, 482200, 513007, 282694, 151054, 193009, 351759, 276700, 351173, 312431, 241969, 497504, 439203, 476592, 463708, 161423, 174613, 561173, 233971, 435547, 421827, 218490, 476705, 471835, 445989, 397850, 79283, 530978, 293301, 573716, 498907, 124356, 480029, 0]]
    
    # Initialize Model
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    m.options.SOLVER = 1
    m.options.IMODE = 3

    # VARIABLES
    print("Creating variables...")

    # warehouse locations
    warehouses_to_hexagon_vars = []
    for dks_id in range(n_warehouses):
        warehouses_to_hexagon_vars.append([m.Var(value=0, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True, name=f"dk_{dks_id}_{hex_id}")
                                           for hex_id in df_aggreg["hex_id_basic"].unique()])
    # hexagon assigned to warehouse
    hexagon_to_warehouse_vars = []
    for hex_id in df_aggreg["hex_id_basic"].unique():
        hexagon_to_warehouse_vars.append([m.Var(value=0, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True, name=f"hx_{hex_id}_{dks_id}")
                                          for dks_id in range(n_warehouses)])
    
    # CONSTRAINTS

    # A warehouse located only in one hexagon
    print("Creating constraints...")
    for dks_vars in warehouses_to_hexagon_vars:
        m.Equation(m.sum(dks_vars) == 1)

    # One hexagon contains at most one warehouse
    for hex_id in df_aggreg["hex_id_basic"].unique():
        m.Equation(m.sum([dks_vars[hex_id] for dks_vars in warehouses_to_hexagon_vars]) <= 1)

    # One hexagon assigned only to one warehouse
    for hex_vars in hexagon_to_warehouse_vars:
        m.Equation(m.sum(hex_vars) == 1)

    # WARM START
    for dks_id in range(n_warehouses):
        warehouses_to_hexagon_vars[dks_id][randint(0, len(warehouses_to_hexagon_vars[dks_id]) - 1)].value = 1

    for hex_id in range(len(hexagon_to_warehouse_vars)):
        hexagon_to_warehouse_vars[hex_id][randint(0, n_warehouses - 1)].value = 1
    
    # Set objective function
    print("Creating objective function...")
    for wh_id in range(n_warehouses):
        for hex_id_1 in df_aggreg["hex_id_basic"].unique():
            for hex_id_2 in df_aggreg["hex_id_basic"].unique():
                distance_hexagon_to_warehouse = int(distance_matrix[hex_id_1][hex_id_2])
                demand_hexagon = df_aggreg.loc[df_aggreg["hex_id_basic"] == hex_id_2, "value"].values[0]
                m.Obj(warehouses_to_hexagon_vars[wh_id][hex_id_1] * 
                      hexagon_to_warehouse_vars[hex_id_2][wh_id] * 
                      distance_hexagon_to_warehouse *
                      demand_hexagon)
    
    # Solve simulation
    m.solve()
```

Comment: The solver should provide the same solution every time with the same inputs. Could you post your code that you used to generate these results?

Comment: Hey John, thanks for the answer. I've noticed that the different result every time is because of a random warm start. However, if I remove the warm start, the final solution is much worse than other that the solver finds when using the warm start. Do you know how I could get the optimal solution?

Comment: It appears that your objective function is nonlinear but all of your constraints are linear. One thing to try is to set the minlp_gap_tol  https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver for the solver closer to zero to get a unique and optimal solution if the problem is convex. If the problem is non-convex then a multi start method (as you have written) is a good approach. You can parallelize the many starts such as shown here: https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/ParallelComputing and select the best solution. Please solve locally if you do this to not overload the servers.

Comment: I've tried to increase the minlp_gap_tol but still having the same results. I will go with the parallel option. Thanks for the help John!

Comment: Thanks - keep me updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented a parallel solution in which I run the same model n times but with a different initial solution each. Once all models have been solved, I take the solution with lowest objective value.